# json parsing result not displayed in Textfield [Nativescript]

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-services, angular2-nativescript

- I'm new  to nativescript. I reffered official grocery app listview in
  Documentation and I used this [Sample API](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/) to parse json format
  datas into listview.
- It seems I'm not getting any error in command prompt. And also in the
  coding side it didn't shown any issue.
- I thought I got an issue when parsing results and displayed in
  textField.I don't know where I did wrong. I'm getting blank screen
  finally.

Below I have posted relevant codes.Please check it.

**Command Prompt Logs:**

[image]

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MyHttpGetService } from "./app.component.services";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import {Grocery} from "./grocery.model";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    providers: [MyHttpGetService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


   groceryList: Array<Grocery> = [];

  constructor(private myHttpGetService: MyHttpGetService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myHttpGetService.load()
      .subscribe(loadedGroceries => {
        loadedGroceries.forEach((groceryObject) => {
          this.groceryList.unshift(groceryObject);
        });
      });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<ListView [items]="groceryList" class="small-spacing">
  <ng-template let-item="item">
    <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
  </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

**app.services.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

import { Grocery } from "./grocery.model";


@Injectable()
export class MyHttpGetService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  static apiUrl = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

  load() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.http.get(MyHttpGetService.apiUrl, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(data => {
      let groceryList = [];
      data.Result.forEach((contacts) => {
        groceryList.push(new Grocery(contacts.id, contacts.name));
      });
      return groceryList;
    })
    .catch(this.handleErrors);
  }

  handleErrors(error: Response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
}
```

**grocery.model.ts:**

```
export class Grocery {
  constructor(public origin: string,public url: string) {

  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: it's interesting how you have `export class **Grocery**`, i've never seen `*`'s used in class before

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I just tried to add class name as bold.that's impossible.